# Passing object to onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop

I want the AJAX callback to trigger the alert() in myFucntion with "It worked" do how can I refer to the myobject object as this in ajaxResponse?

```
function myobject() {
    this.val = "worked";

    http.onreadystatechange = function ajaxResponse() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            this.myFunction();
        }

        http.send(null);  
    }

    myobject.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    alert("it "+this.val);
}
```

Comment: My question is how can I call this.value in ajaxResponse and that refer to the value in the object that contains this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajaxResponse is a function in parent function, it's called closure in javascript. When a closure uses a variable which is defined in its parent function, this variable can not be destroyed from memory, while the father function finishes execution.
So, define a temporary variable like this:

```
var objTmp = this;
```

Then you can use this variable objTmp in ajaxResponse.
Or you can do it like this:

```
http.onreadystatechange = (function(objTmp){
                         return 
                             function ajaxResponse{alert(objTmp.value)}
                       })(this)
```

Comment: That creates a global variable though which defeats the point of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Just append the parent object to the xhr object, like this:

```
http.parent = this; // Append it here
http.onreadystatechange = function ajaxResponse()
{
    if (http.readyState == 4)
        alert(this.parent.value) // Access it here
}
```

Comment: This has worked but only for    

myobject.prototype.myFunction=function(){
alert("it "+this.val);
}  

if then do  if (http.readyState == 4) {this.myObject.myFunction();}

myobject.prototype.myObject={
callback:myFunction(){
alert("it "+this.val);
}  
} 
it falls apart.